# IM across VLANs

Tags: vlan

My workplace (a public library) employs two VLANs to service public machines and staff machines separately. The help desk techs are requesting an IM system such that a patron at a machine hooked into the public side VLAN can page and chat with a help desk technician, who's machine is hooked into our staff VLAN. They feel this will help increase their productivity in serving patrons.

So my superiors are wanting to avoid a LAN based IM system due to the difficulties of communicating across VLANs. Consequently they wish to pursue the option to use an Internet based IM system to achieve this. We currently use Microsoft Lync 2010 on the staff side to facilitate IM between staff members, and this includes the help desk techs. If there were some way to achieve them having IM access to patron machines and fellow staff simultaneously, without having separate software, this would be ideal.

Discussion regarding either a VLAN based solution or an Internet based solution are more than welcome. Thank you in advance for your expertise.

Comment: "So my superiors are wanting to avoid a LAN based IM system due to the difficulties of communicating across VLANs." - The world runs like this, there is no difficulties setting up IM systems across VLANs unless you don't know what you are doing...

Comment: Communication across VLANs is not difficult at all, it only requires a router. But if the real problem is "we don't want the two networks to talk at all", then no IM system is going to help you.

Comment: Why not route the public VLAN side to a Lync Edge server with an external IP?

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the dilemma. Google Talk, Skype, AIM, AIM Express, Yahoo Messenger, etc., etc. - None of these require the two VLAN's to be connected in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Use literally ANYTHING that's Internet based. Use Skype, Yahoo, Jabber, IRC, Google, .

Also, your Lync Server paired with an EDGE server allows clients to connect from externally. You can also federate your Lync with Skype or Yahoo or Jabber.

Comment: Internet based == IP based?